# Borel sigma algebra on measures generated by distance inducing weak convergence and the one generated by weak topology

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the vector space of Borel finite signed measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$. On $\mathcal{M}$ we can consider the weak topology $\tau$: the coarsest topology on $\mathcal{M}$ s.t. all the maps $\mu \mapsto \int \varphi d\mu$ are continuous on varying of $\varphi \in C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the continuous and bounded real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Suppose $\{f_k\}_{k \ge 1} \subset C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a sequence of functions s.t. $\sup_k \sup_x |f_k(x)| \le 1$ and s.t.
$$\mu_n \overset{\tau}{\to}\mu \text{ iff } \int f_k d \mu_n \to \int f_k d \mu \quad \forall \, k \ge 1.$$

Then we can define the distance $d$ on $\mathcal{M}$ as $$ d(\mu, \nu) = \sum_k 2^{-k} \left | \int f_k d \mu - \int f_k d \nu \right |$$

and we have a topology on $\mathcal{M}$ generated by $d$, call it $\tau_d$. Of course $\tau \subset \tau_d$ (but they have the same converging sequences) and then $\sigma(\tau) \subset \sigma(\tau_d)$, where $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ denotes the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathcal{E} \subset 2^{\mathcal{M}}$.

Is it possible to prove also the opposite inclusion i.e. that the Borel sigma algebra generated by those two topologies actually coincide?

Comment: Yes. Actually, $\tau=\tau_d$.

Comment: Are you sure? I think $\tau$ is not metrisable...

Comment: You are right, I misread what you wrote and thought you were writing about positive measures.

Comment: Yes, in case I restrict $\tau$ to positive measures this is true. I thought to the following argument but I am not sure: if $B \in \sigma(\tau_d)$ I can consider the sets $B_n := B \cap \{ |\mu| \le n \}$. I think that $\tau |_{B_n} = \tau_d |_{B_n}$ (I am not completely sure) so that $B_n \in \sigma(\tau)$. However $B= \cup_n B_n$, so that $B \in \sigma(\tau)$ and then $\sigma(\tau_d) \subset \sigma(\tau)$. Let me know if it convinces you...

Comment: I'm not completely sure. If you would replace $\mathbb{R}^d$ by a compact metric space, the metrizability of $\tau|B_n$ follows from functional analytic machinery. Here, I don't know.

Comment: This is exactly the point where I am not sure..

Comment: It turns out, that space is not metrizable either. According to Proposition 3.1.8. of Bogachev's new book on weak convergence, the space of signed Radon measures of variation at most 1 on a metric space is not metrizable if the metric space is not compact.

Comment: I see...thank you! What if I take $B_n := B \cap \{ |\mu| \le n \} \cap \{ \text{supp}(\mu) \subset \{ |x| \le n\} \}$? Seems too simple...

Comment: That only gives you the compactly supported measures.

Comment: I see... maybe there is some other argument.....

Comment: By the way, if the sequence $\{f_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is not carefully chosen, then the series in the definition of the metric $d_p$ can be divergent. Maybe one should impose a condition that $\sup_{k\in\mathbb N}\|f_k\|<\infty$?

Comment: Yes, I can take it with norm bounded by 1.

Comment: Since $(f_k)$ seems to be rather arbitrary, is it possible to replace this sequence by $(f_1^+,f_1^-,f_2^+,f_2^-,...)$. Maybe the arguments become a little bit easier.

Comment: Actually I can define $\{f_k\}_{k \ge 1} = \{ 1 \} \cup \left (\cup_n \cup_m \cup_j f_{m,n,j} \right )$ where $f_{m,n,j}$ is a smooth function identically one on $B_{1/m}(x_n)$ and identically $0$ outside $B_{1/m +1/j}(x_n)$, where $\{x_n\}_{n \ge 1} = \mathbb{Q}^d$. In this way all the functions are already nonnegative and uniformly bounded. I didn't specify it because I thought it was not important...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Borel $\sigma$-algebras generated by these two topologies seem to be equal.

The idea of the proof is as follows. Let $\mathcal M_+$ be the subspace of $\mathcal M$ consisting of measures. It is known that the weak topology on $\mathcal M_+$ is metrizable and the space $\mathcal M_+$ is Polish. Consider the subspace $$\mathcal P=\{(\lambda,\mu)\in\mathcal M_+\times\mathcal M_+:\lambda\perp\mu\}.$$ The symbol $\lambda\perp\mu$ means that there are disjoint $\sigma$-compact subsets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ such that $\lambda(A)=\lambda(\mathbb R^d)$, $\mu(B)=\mu(\mathbb R^d)$ and $\lambda(B)=\mu(A)=0$.
It can be shown that the set $\mathcal P$ is Borel (of type $F_{\sigma\delta}$) in $\mathcal M_+\times\mathcal M_+$.

Now consider the map $$r:\mathcal P\to\mathcal M,\quad r:(\lambda,\mu)\mapsto\lambda-\mu$$and observe that it is continuous and bijective (as each sign-measure uniquely decomposes into its positive and negative parts).
Since $\sup_{k\in\mathbb N}\|f_k\|<\infty$, the map $r$ also is also continuous with respect to the topology $\tau_d$ on $\mathcal M$.

Since the Tychonoff space $\mathcal M$ is a continuous image of the metrizable separable space $\mathcal P$, it has countable network of the topology and hence admits a continuous injective map $\psi:\mathcal M\to \mathbb R^\omega$ to the  Polish space $\mathbb R^\omega$.

For any $\tau_d$-open set $U\subseteq \mathcal M$ the preimage $r^{-1}[U]$ is an open set in $\mathcal P$. By the classical Lusin-Souslin Theorem (15.1 in Kechris' book), the image of any Borel subset of $\mathcal P$ under the injective continuous map $\psi\circ r$ is Borel in the Polish space $\mathbb R^\omega$.  In particular, the set $V=\psi\circ r[r^{-1}[U]]$ is Borel in $\mathbb R^\omega$ and hence the set $U=\psi^{-1}[V]$ is Borel in $\mathcal M$. This implies that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\tau_d)$ generated by the topology $\tau_d$ is contained in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\tau)$ generated by the topology $\tau$. On the other hand, the inclusion $\sigma(\tau)\subseteq \sigma(\tau_d)$ follows from the metrizability of the topology $\tau_d$ and the sequential continuity of the indentity map $(\mathcal M,\tau_d)\to\mathcal M$.

Comment: The argument above allows me to conclude that $\sigma(\tau) \subset \sigma(\tau_d)$. Is it not already obvious from $\tau \subset \tau_d$? I need the opposite inclusion...

Comment: The obvious direction is $\sigma(\tau_d)\subseteq \sigma(\tau)$ because the metrizable topology is contained in the weak topology. What I have written is the non-obvious direction $\sigma(\tau)\subseteq \sigma(\tau_d)$.

Comment: I’m sorry, I am confused: if $E$ is $\tau$-closed, then $E$ is sequentially $\tau$-closed. Then it is sequentially $\tau_d$-closed i.e. it is $\tau_d$-closed hence $\tau\subset \tau_d$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Ups! I have just understood that your metric $d_p$ does not generate the weakest topology in which all integrals $\int f_kd\mu$ are continuous. So, this changes the situation. Let me think a bit more.

Comment: Oh thanks god: I started questioning everything!

Comment: Maybe the same argument with $U$ open in $\tau_d$ may work...

Comment: But in the Borel sense this does not change anything. Just decompose $\mathcal M$ into the countable union $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\mathcal M_n$ where $\mathcal M_n=\{\mu\in\mathcal M:\|\mu\|\le n\}$. On the sets $\mathcal M_n$ the metric $d_p$ does generate the weakest topology generated by the integrals $\int f_nd \mu$. So, on these sets $\tau_d\subseteq\tau$ and the converse follows from the metrizability of $\tau_d$. So, the topologies $\tau$ and $\tau_d$ generate the same Borel $\sigma$-algebras on the closed sets $\mathcal M_n$ and because of that the Borel $\sigma$-algebras are the same.

Comment: Oh nice! I will think about it!

Comment: Even if it seems to suggest that on $\mathcal{M}_n$ the two topologies coincide, which is impossibile, since $\tau$ is not metrisable even when restricted to $\mathcal{M}_n$.

Comment: It is not compact in the $\tau$ topology, since it is not tight. Notice that $\mathcal{M}$ is not the dual of $C_b(\mathcal{R}^d)$. Michael Greinecker pointed this out too in the above comments.

Comment: It seems that you are right: the weak topology on $\mathcal M_n$ is non-metrizable (because of non-compactness of $\mathbb R^d$).

Comment: Then the argument I have written in my answer should work, maybe modulo decomposition of $\mathcal M$ into the union $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\mathcal M_n$ in order to guarantee that the metric $\tau_d$ restricted to $\mathcal M_n$ generates a weaker topology than $\tau$.

Comment: A substantial amount of energy should be spent for struggle with this unnaturally chosen metric $d_p$. As I understand that had to be a metric generating the weakest topology in which all integrals $\int f_kd\mu$ are continuous? So, maybe just redefine this metric and then everything will be a bit easier?

Comment: No, $d$ does not generate the coarsest topology for which the maps $\mu \mapsto \int f_k d \mu$ are continuous. This last topology indeed coincides with $\tau$, I think. Then it is not metrisable. Unfortunately I am working on some other people work and I cannot change the metric $d$.
Maybe a possible choice for the $\mathcal{M}_{n}$ is the following: $\mathcal{M}_{n} = \text{cl} \left (\cap_m \cup_k \{ |\mu| \le n , \mu(\{x > m\}) \le 1/k \} \right )$. These should be compact subsets which union is $\mathcal{M}$ and $\tau | \mathcal{M}_n$ should me metrisable. What do you think?

Comment: Moreover, may the argument of the answer with $U \subset \mathcal{M}$ open in $\tau_d$ work? I should be able to prove in the same way that $U \in \sigma(\tau)$...

Comment: Yes, see the comments to the question, the $f_k$ are uniformly bounded.

Comment: @Bremen000 I have adjusted the argument. Now it should work for your metric (with uniformly bounded sequence $(f_k)_{k\in\omega}$).

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit. Just a last question: why do you have to introduce the space $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$? Is it not enough to work with the Souslin space $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: @Bremen000 The space $\mathbb R^\omega$ is necessary if we would like to apply the classical form of Lusin-Souslin Theorem, which is formulated in Kechris for Polish spaces. But of course, there are generalizations of Lusin-Souslin Theorem applicable to injective maps with values in functionally Hausdorff Souslin spaces. But in the latter case one should find a proper reference. Instead of finding such a reference I just made this short reduction via $\mathbb R^\omega$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I found Theorem 6.8.6 in "Measure Theory - Volume 2" by Bogachev, this should work. Finally I think that my argument with $\mathcal{M}_n$ above is not correct. A possible correct one could be the following: for every $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ I can consider the set $\mathcal{M}_{f,n} := \cap_k\{ |\mu| \le n, \mu ( \{x > f(k)\}) < 1/k ) \}$. Then $\overline{\mathcal{M}_n}$ is compact in $\mathcal{M}$ hence metrisable. It should also be that $\mathcal{M} = \cup_{f,n}\mathcal{M}_{f,n}$ so the argument with $\tau | \mathcal{M}_{f,n}$ should work.

Comment: @Bremen000 The problem with such sets like $\mathcal M_n$ is that the space $\mathcal M$ does not seem to be $\sigma$-compact, so the problem cannot be reduced to the compact case.

Comment: Do you have any reference for the non sigma compactness of $\mathcal{M}$? It's a shame, the argument with the $\mathcal{M}_{f,n}$ seemed to be correct...